# When building a Xamarin Forms app for Google Play is there a need to generate more than on ABI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have "Generate one package per selected ABI" selected and this is what it creates:

I am working with Xamarin Forms

```
com.xx.xx-arm64-v8a.apk
com.xx.xx-armeabi-v7.apk
com.xx.xx-x86_64.apk
com.xx.xx-x86.apk
com.xx.xx.apk
```

My question is do I need to have anything other than the "com.xx.xx.apk" file and if I publish with then does the Google play store just receive that or does it receive all of the other files as well?

Comment: the *com.xx.xx.apk* contains all other apks

Comment: So is there ever a time when you need to select Generate one package per selected ABI?  When would I need to select that?

Comment: hey go through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows